# Do the task in order in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, botkit

i want to do these tasks in order
but the results is not in order
it's like 
2
3
10
9
1
4
6
5
7
8

The API is from the NodeJS toolkit [telegraf](http://telegraf.js.org/)

```
bot.hears('numbers', (ctx) => {

  ctx.reply("1")
  ctx.reply("2")
  ctx.reply("3")
  ctx.reply("4")
  ctx.reply("5")
  ctx.reply("6")
  ctx.reply("7")
  ctx.reply("8")
  ctx.reply("9")
  ctx.reply("10")
})
```

.then() will solve my problem but i have problem with for loop
.then() is not work here

```
var x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for (var key in x) {
      ctx.reply(`x`, Extra.HTML().markup((m) =>
        m.inlineKeyboard([
          m.callbackButton(`A`, `C`),
          m.callbackButton(`B`, `D`)
        ])
      )) .then(() => ctx.reply("*****************"))
    }
```

this is not the real code , var x is an complicated object and A,B,C,D are related to x , i just simpelized code

```js
//// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ~ # In The Name Of God # ~  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \\\\

//// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Defenitions , Variables  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \\\\

const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const { Extra, Markup } = require('telegraf')
var token = '423782049:AAEvytBA8RtllgnCm_GFMfeP4ttTz6qsAGA';
const bot = new Telegraf(token)
var request = require('request');
var inputdevices;
var inputdevicesstatus;

//// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Start Command  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \\\\

bot.command('start', (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply("به خانه هوشمند خوش آمدید")
    .then(() => ctx.reply('گزینه مورد نظر رو از منو انتخاب کنید', Markup
      .keyboard([
        ['کلید ها', ' سناریو'],
      ])
      .oneTime()
      .resize()
      .extra()
    ))
})

//// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Hears کلید ها  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \\\\

bot.hears('کلید ها', (ctx) => {

  ctx.reply("1")
    .then(() => ctx.reply("2"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("3"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("4"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("5"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("6"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("7"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("8"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("9"))
    .then(() => ctx.reply("10"))
    var x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for (var key in x) {
  ctx.reply(`x`, Extra.HTML().markup((m) =>
    m.inlineKeyboard([
      m.callbackButton(`A`, `C`),
      m.callbackButton(`B`, `D`)
    ])
  )) .then(() => ctx.reply("*****************"))
}
})
bot.startConversation(
  
)


//// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Action خاموش کلید  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \\\\


bot.action(/خاموش کلید/, (ctx) => {
  //console.log(ctx.match.input)
  var idxnumber = ctx.match.input.substring(ctx.match.input.indexOf('<%>'), ctx.match.input.lastIndexOf('<%>'))
  idxnumber = idxnumber.replace(/<%>/g, '');
  console.log(idxnumber)
  var switchname = ctx.match.input.substring(ctx.match.input.indexOf('<#>'), ctx.match.input.lastIndexOf('<#>'));
  switchname = switchname.replace(/<#>/g, '');
  console.log(switchname)
  request(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=${idxnumber}&switchcmd=Off`, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error == null) {
      inputdevicesstatus = JSON.parse(body)
      if (inputdevicesstatus.status == "OK") {
        ctx.reply(`کلید ${switchname} خاموش شد`)
      }
      else {
        ctx.reply(`در خاموش شدن ${switchname} اختلال به وجود آمده است`)
      }

    }
    else {
      console.log("ارتباط با دیتابیس برقرار نشد ، لطفا دوباره تلاش کنید");
      ctx.reply("ارتباط با دیتابیس برقرار نشد ، لطفا دوباره تلاش کنید")
    }

  })

})

//////////////////

bot.startPolling()
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more info? Are you using any libraries? What are "hears" and "reply"?

Comment: Are the replay functions asynchronous?  Do they have a callback?  If they do, then each subsequent call needs to be in the callback of the previous method.

Comment: From the Github docs for [Botkit](https://www.botkit.ai/): *"Messages sent using bot.reply() are sent immediately. If multiple messages are sent via bot.reply() in a single event handler, they will arrive in the client very quickly and may be difficult for the user to process. We recommend using **bot.startConversation() if more than one message needs to be sent.**"* (emphasis mine)

Comment: You have something going on asynchronously.  It would help if you could explain what `ctx.reply` is.  If it returns a promise, it would be a simple matter to chain them together: `Promise.resolve().then(() => ctx.reply('1')).then(() => ctx.reply('2')) ... .then(() => ctx.reply('10'))`

Comment: i use telegram bot api telegraf